# Selecting count of occurences of values in kdb

Tags: kdb

How to count occurences of distinct values from one column in another column in kdb. The idea is to return the count of values in another column.

The table looks like
Col1 : x,y,z and Col2: x,x,l
The idea is to find count of occurences of x,y,z from col1 in col2, which in above case is 2,0,0

Comment: Can you provide an example table please?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
tab:([]col1:`x`y`z;col2:`x`x`w)

q)exec([]distinct col1)!0^([]count each group col2)distinct col1 from tab
col1| col2
----| ----
x   | 2
y   | 0
z   | 0
```

Comment: I am getting error as kdb error: nyi while running above query. I also have to select from date range.. thanks for your answer

Comment: Also, if two columns are from two tables. Can we modify the query. Say t1, col1: x,y,z and t2, col2: x,x,y,z,c,v,b. Find occurences of x from t1 in t2. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I can't help you with the error unless you supply a more accurate example that replicates your error. For your second question you can use a modified version of Antons answer ```update freq:0^(count each group t2`col2)col1 from t1```

Answer (score 0):

Desired value can be found as a map of `Col2` occurrences. Which is later looked up by values from `Col1`

```
t: ([] Col1:`x`y`z; Col2:`x`x`l);
update Col1Col2Count: 0^(count each group Col2) Col1 from t
```